# How to implement Zendesk in Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app and I'm trying to integrate Zendesk for customer support. I'm struggling to find any resources or examples for how to do this in Flutter, so I thought I'd reach out to the community for some help.

Has anyone successfully implemented Zendesk in a Flutter app before? If so, could you please share your approach and any resources you used? Specifically, I'm looking to:

```
- Add a help center to the app
- Allow users to submit tickets from within the app
- Display ticket status and history
```

Any advice, code snippets, or examples would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own FloatingButton that opens a dialog with a form.

That's my provider to send zendesk ticket

```
class ZendeskProvider {
  const ZendeskProvider({
    required HttpProvider httpProvider,
    required Environment environment,
  })  : _environment = environment,
        _httpProvider = httpProvider;

  final HttpProvider _httpProvider;
  final Environment _environment;

  String get _token => _environment.zendeskToken; // your zendesk token here
  String get _host => 'https://[YOUR_ACCOUNT].zendesk.com/api/v2/requests.json'; // Your account zendesk host

  Future<void> report({
    required ReportInfos reportInfos,
  }) async {
    final response = await _httpProvider.doRequest(HttpRequest.post(
      _host,
      '',
      httpParams: HttpParams(
        body: {
          'request': {
            'comment': {'body': reportInfos.body, 'uploads': []},
            'fields': {
              '360024868852': reportInfos.reason,
              '360048922472': reportInfos.name,
            },
            'requester': {
              'email': reportInfos.email,
              'locale_id': 19,
              'name': reportInfos.email.split('@')[0],
            },
            'subject': reportInfos.reason,
            'tags': ['${reportInfos.device}_widget'],
            'ticket_form_id': null,
            'via_id': 48,
          },
        },
      ),
    )..addHeader({'Authorization': 'Basic $reportInfos.email/token:$_token'}));

    if (response.status != HttpStatus.success) {
      throw Error();
    }
  }
}
```

You can send this request when form submitted.

These are the args I need to send to Zendesk, some of then I get through the form, others, like device, I set with web or mobile.

```
class ReportInfos {
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String reason;
  final String device;
  final String body;

  ReportInfos({
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
    required this.reason,
    required this.device,
    required this.body,
  });
}
```